# Allow access to special file in htaccess

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, security, web

In my .htaccess file I want to allow access to some special php files with query string, for example:

```
myFile.php?c=1&b=2
```

I tried many way but did not work. How can I do this?

Comment: Why .htaccess, `/myFile.php?c=1&b=2` can be accessed without any rewrite rules.

Comment: :( I installed wordpress on my hosting but default .htaccess does not work, I must add new rules manually